# C# pincer for loop

Tags: c#, algorithm, for-loop

Trying to implement a simple for loop that works 0 and the end at the same time, the problem i'm running into though is that it only works on even amounts of items. For odd numbered items it does'nt return the last item.

```
int x = 10;
for(int i=0; i!= x; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + " " +x + " ");
    x--;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code above, 5 won't be printed because at that time `i` is equal to `x` which violates the loop condition and exits the loop. Hence the value is not printed. Changing the loop condition from `i != x` to `i<=x` will fix the problem. This is shown below.

```
        int x = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++, x--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + " " + x + " ");
        }
```

Hope it helps :)